# How can hasFocus knoukoutjs data binding work on a textarea form input

Tags: knockout.js

I have a simple knockoutJS code to increase the rows of a textarea when the textarea has focus.

```html
    <div class='liveExample'> 
       <input type="text" value="" />
       <textarea data-bind="hasFocus: $root.applyIncreaseCols,  attr: { rows : 
     lines }"> </textarea>

       </div>
```

```
var myModel = function() {

    this.lines=ko.observable("1");

    this.applyIncreaseCols = function(){
    //document.getElementById("thisone").cols="100";

    //alert("damn right");
     this.lines("3");

    };


 }

ko.applyBindings(new myModel());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subscribe to an observable bound to the hasFocus attribute and toggle the amount of lines/rows here?

I've added a simple and little bit more advanced solution, the first just basically does what you were looking for.

The second one adds up all linebreaks in its content and uses that to define the required amount of rows + 1. You could check for a min and max value and maybe have a slightly less jumping form, atleast with a more natural feel to it.

```js
var myModel = function() {
  //to make sure we're working against the myModel scope
  var self = this; 
  
  // simple expanding textarea
  self.lines = ko.observable(1);
  self.isFocus = ko.observable(false);
  self.isFocus.subscribe(function(isFocus) {
    self.lines(isFocus ? 3 : 1);
  });
  
  // expanding textarea by amount linebreaks + 1
  self.lines2 = ko.observable(2);
  self.content2 = ko.observable('');
  self.content2.subscribe(function (content2) {
    var linebreaks = content2.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).length;
    self.lines2(linebreaks + 1);
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new myModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class='liveExample'>
  simple:
  <textarea data-bind="hasFocus: isFocus, attr: { rows: lines }"> </textarea>
  <br />
  advanced:
  <textarea data-bind="attr: { rows: lines2 }, textInput: content2"> </textarea>
</div>
```